# Cómo puedo cerrar la sesión de una página privada en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tengo una web en wordpress y una de las páginas es privada, es decir, se accede a través de contraseña.

Hace un tiempo instalé el plugin [Protected Posts Logout Button](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/protected-posts-logout-button/) que añade un botón de logout para devolver al usuario a la página. Haciendo de esta manera un estilo de cerrar sesión.

Ha pasado un tiempo y los desarrolladores del plugin han dejado de actualizarlo. ¿Alguien sabe alguna manera para hacer lo mismo? Ya sea por medio de otro plugin o por código.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar a insertar este código en un botón por ejemplo para que te devuelva a la home después de hacer logout:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Logout</a>
```

[Fuente](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url)

Comment: Muchas gracias! funciona correctamente. La única pega que le veo es que si estoy usando la web como administrador del sitio, al hacer logout de esa página privada en concreto, me saca de toda la sesión de wordpress. Pero... no me importa. Por cierto, si quiero que no me redirija la home, sino a una página interna... ¿cómo debería hacerlo?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( URLPARALAREDIRECCION ); ?>">Logout</a>

Comment: Todo aclarado, muchas gracias!